# Formfile getFilename and filtering

Tags: java, jsp, file-upload, upload, struts

Does the `getFileName()` method of the `FormFile` interface of struts does filtering on the name of the file ?
[Struts documentation for method `getfileName`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/upload/FormFile.html#getFileName%28%29)

I mean, following  [Struts documentation for upload](http://wiki.apache.org/struts/StrutsFileUpload), the "Whats Needed in the Action" part.

**If the filename supplied by the user is `"../../../toto.ext"`, does `myFile.getFileName()` return `"toto.ext"` , or `"../../../toto.ext"`.**

According to [Struts documentation for method `getfileName`](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.2.x/api/org/apache/struts/upload/FormFile.html#getFileName%28%29) ,**"Returns the file name of this file. This is the base name of the file, as supplied by the user when the file was uploaded."**, it 's supposed to return  `"../../../toto.ext"`. But I'm not so sure.

could you light me on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

File name is a name taken from folder contents like `"toto.ext"`. But `"../../../toto.ext"` is not a name of file, it's a file path, which include the file name. The path is relative to the current directory. You should distinguish between base path name and relative path. Base path + file name give you the absolute path.